# How to fade out dynamically generated headers based on divs not containing search terms?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to fade out headers of a jQuery accordion that do not contain the search terms I input (hiding/fading the header is enough to make the "pop-up" divs not show using jQuery accordions, as the header cannot be clicked and the divs will never be set to "active") but I am clearly doing something wrong as the dinamically generated headers are not being faded out as I expect to. For example, if I search for a term contained only in the last div being generated, the previous headers and divs will not be faded out. This leads me to think that the problem is clearly in the `$this.closest(".infoDiv").next(".header").fadeIn();` especially the "next" part, but as I am very inexperienced with jQuery, I have no idea how to target only the headers of divs not containing my search term. I am sure its something trivial but I cannot figure it out so I would appreciate some help.

This is the form that I use to input my search term.

```html
    <div class="search-container">
        <form class="form-search">
            <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search in events...">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This is the dinamically generated header and div:

```html
<?php if(!empty($results)) {foreach ($results as $row) {?>
    <h3 class = "header"><?php echo $row['society_name']; ?> - <?php echo $row['event_name']; ?> - <?php echo $row['event_date']; ?></h3>
    <div class = "infoDiv">
        <p style ="display:none;"><span class = "data"> <?php echo $row['society_name']; ?> - <?php echo $row['event_name']; ?> - <?php echo $row['event_date']; ?> </span></p>
        <p><img src="addressHere"></p>
        <p><b>Description:</b><span class = "data"><?php echo $row['description']; ?> </span></p>
        <p><b>Schedule:</b><span class = "data"><?php echo $row['schedule']; ?> </span></p>
        <p><b>Location:</b><span class = "data"><?php echo $row['location']; ?> </span></p>
        <p><b>Frequency:</b><span class = "data"><?php echo $row['frequency']; ?> </span></p>
        <p><b>Event Tags:</b><span class = "data"><?php echo $row["GROUP_CONCAT(c.event_tag SEPARATOR ', ')"]; ?> </span></p>
        <span style="display:none;" class="eventId"> <?php echo $row['event_id'] ?> </span>
        <button class="addToList"> Add to My Events List </button>
    </div>
<?php }} ?>
```

And this is the jQuery script that I wrote:

```js
$('.form-search').on('submit',function(){
    return false;
});

$('.form-search .btn').on('click', function(){
    var query = $.trim($(this).prevAll('.search-query').val()).toLowerCase();
    $('div.infoDiv .data').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) === -1) {
            $this.closest(".infoDiv").next(".header").fadeOut();
        } else {
            $this.closest(".infoDiv").next(".header").fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

*EDIT: this is an example of what is being generated in the DOM https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWPdR.jpg

Comment: Could you please add an example of the -dynamically generated header and div- code, the one the DOM contains, just to check what is being generated...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL i just edited my post with a link to an image! thanks :)